# No WCF service response - C#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have added a service reference, directed to a WSDL which loaded all existing WSDLs from the location. I am trying to request data by calling one of the methods like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fLastname, folder, status, header, responsible;
    int date;
    PyramidServices.ServiceSoapClient client = new PyramidServices.ServiceSoapClient();
    string activity = client.GetUserActivity("xxxx", "xxxx", out fLastname, out folder, out status, out date, out header, out responsible);
}
```

When debugging, the vars are all null. . I have a hard time understanding trace messages since this is not my field. I don't know what to look for, so here is pretty much all the information I get when tracing (Sorry for the Swedish version!):

**Sending:**
[image]
**Receiving:**
[image]
**Answer @ Channel:**
[image]
**Stop:**
[image]

**[EDIT]**

I tested the method using WCF Test Client and received following:

[image]
[image]

So it's kind of obvious that I am doing something wrong with the code when parsing the data from the response? My question is, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to use [WCF Test Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It allows you to easily see the request/response messages

Comment: @LukasKubis Nope :o I'll take a look at that!

Comment: @LukasKubis I used WCF Test Client and got two tabs, Formatted and XML. The formatted says "null" at all posts, just like within Visual Studio. But the XML tab got the expected envelope. How do I get this particular envelope within visual studio or simply, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of help from @TomW, we finally found out what the problem was. The code for the WSDL is created in a system that lets me add XML nodes surrounding the data like below:

```
<wrap>
    <data1></data1>
    <data2></data2>
    <data3></data3>
</wrap>
```

instead of:

```
<data1></data1>
<data2></data2>
<data3></data3>

<data1></data1>
<data2></data2>
<data3></data3> 

<data1></data1>
<data2></data2>
<data3></data3>
```

Therefor, the code generated by Visual Studio in Service Reference did not like the way I wrapped the data with unwanted tags. After removing the tag from my code in the system, I received exactly what I wanted with the code at the top.